# Fix PHP Timezone warning

Tags: php

After installing a php application my site loads the app with a warning overlayed on the page

> Warning: strftime() [function.strftime]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier.

I believe the problem is that there is no timezone set in php.ini on this server. My server company doesn't think that this is something they should have configured when they set up the server, so how do I edit the php.ini file and what do I insert to get rid of this error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure about editing the php.ini file, but I always [set the default time zone](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) as part of a config include

```
<?php date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London'); ?>
```

Comment: thanks, it worked fine, but is that okay , dont we face any problem ?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do the fix the problem in the `php.ini`, you can use [date.timezone](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone) like:

```
date.timezone = "THETIMEZONE"
```

If you want to do in the php script, you can use the [date_default_timezone_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) function:

```
date_default_timezone_set("THETIMEZONE");
```

Here you can find the list of the Timezone: http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php